# javascript запрос переменной из другой функции

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети

не работает функция startTesting, каким образом я могу указать что нужне переменные надо брать из startLearning?

```js
function startLearning() {
  var XOR_INPUT = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1]
  ];
  var XOR_IDEAL = [
    [0],
    [1],
    [1],
    [0]
  ];
  var con = ENCOG.GUI.Console.create('out');
  var network = ENCOG.BasicNetwork.create([
    ENCOG.BasicLayer.create(ENCOG.ActivationSigmoid.create(), 2, 1),
    ENCOG.BasicLayer.create(ENCOG.ActivationSigmoid.create(), 3, 1),
    ENCOG.BasicLayer.create(ENCOG.ActivationSigmoid.create(), 1, 0)
  ]);
  network.randomize();

  var train = ENCOG.PropagationTrainer.create(network, XOR_INPUT, XOR_IDEAL, "RPROP", 0, 0);

  var iteration = 1;

  do {
    train.iteration();
    var str = "Training Iteration #" + iteration + ", Error: " + train.error;
    con.writeLine(str);
    iteration++;
  } while (iteration < 1000 && train.error > 0.01);

  var input = [0, 0];
  var output = new Array(1);
}

function startTesting(test_INPUT) {
con.writeLine("Testing neural network");
  for (var i = 0; i < test_INPUT.length; i++) {
    network.compute(test_INPUT[i], output);
    var str = "Input: " + String(test_INPUT[i][0]) + " ; " + String(test_INPUT[i][1]) + "   Output: " + String(output[0]) + "   Ideal: " + String(XOR_IDEAL[i][0]);
    con.writeLine(str);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="encog.js"></script>
  <script src="encog-widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="neuro.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="startLearning()">Learning</button>
  </br>
  <div id="out"></div>
  </br>
  <button onclick="startTesting([[0,1],[1,1]])">Testing</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: объявить переменные вне функции? Из области видимости функции вы их по другому не достанете

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите переменные в общую, для обеих функций, область видимости, либо, как вариант, используйте localStorage.